# Heroku Web Dyno failing

Tags: node.js, heroku

I've made a little Node.js app and want to deploy it on Heroku. I'm following the [Heroku doc](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs) and everything works fine. `foreman start` correctly start my app.

I push it to Heroku, no problem (except a warning because I don't specify the Node.js version, nothing bad) and then, when I want to do the `heroku ps:scale web=1` I have this error :

```
Scaling web dynos... failed
 !    No such type as web.
```

Here is the content of the `Procfile`

```
web: node app.js
```

Any idea ?

Comment: What's the contents of your Procfile?

Comment: Question edited with its content.

Answer (score 8):

Probably you forgot to push `Procfile` to `heroku` as shown below:

```
$ heroku ps:scale web=1
Scaling web dynos... failed
 !    Resource not found
$ git status
# On branch master
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   Procfile
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
$ git add Procfile
$ git commit -m "Add Procfile for Heroku"
$ git push heroku
$ heroku ps:scale web=1
Scaling web dynos... done, now running 1
```

I hope it helps :)

Comment: make sure the Procfile has no file extention (change Procfile.txt to Procfile)

Answer (score 1):

Procfile name is case-sensitive. I had the same problem (named it **procfile**), solved it by removing from git, renaming to **Procfile** and pushing again.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you didn't push your app before trying to scale the dynos. You must do that first. Deployments are executed when pushing to the heroku remote. After that the web/node environment is available and you can proceed to scale the dynos.

Answer (score -4):

```
heroku ps:scale web=1 --app=my-cool-app-name
```

"my-cool-app-name" is the name of the application at "My Apps" screen at the heroku website.